# PHp - memory error when resizing a PNG image

Tags: php, memory, image-manipulation

I have a script that creates a thumbnail out of an uploaded image. it works fine with jpgs, but gives me an error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 26250000 bytes)

when I upload a png image.

The script is:

```
//create thumbnail; $modwidth and height are calculated in another part of the script
//$original is the path to the full sized image

$tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight); 
switch (strrchr($new_image_name,'.')) {
  case ".jpg":
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($original);
    break;
  case ".jpeg":
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($original);
    break;
  case ".png":
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($original);
    break;
  case ".gif":
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($original);
    break;
}
imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, $x_pos, $y_pos, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height); 
switch (strrchr($new_image_name,'.')) {
  case ".jpg":
    imagejpeg($tn, $target_path, 100);
    break;
  case ".jpeg":
    imagejpeg($tn, $target_path, 100);
    break;
  case ".png":
    imagepng($tn, $target_path, 0);
    break;
  case ".gif":
    imagegif($tn, $target_path);
    break;
}
```

As I said it works perfectly with JPGs and also with GIFs. 
That memory error appears only with PNGs, and I have only used a 1.2Mb image.

How can i solve this?
thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` before script.

Comment: Thanks Cesar, it worked.

Do I have to decrease that memory limit after the script? (in general, is there any problem in setting a very high memory limit?)

Comment: No problem, this define the memory only for this script, if you need for all scripts you need to change in php.ini

Comment: To clarify: your image is quite big, if you upload a bigger image your script will fail again. Just try to have a limit on the image size sent to the script.

Comment: This is just moving the goalposts, it has to be said. (i.e.: You'll eventually run out of memory.) If feasible, it's sometimes wise (and faster) to shell out to an external command tool such as ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase memory_limit setting in php.ini to something like this

```
memory_limit = 128M
```