# PHP Image upload problem

Tags: php

I'm having trouble to get the following code to upload large images. It works great with images less than 1000px by 1000px, but breaks on anything bigger. Any help/ideas greatly appreciated.

Note: I have tried increasing the '$memoryNeeded>=10000000' to '7700000000' but still no joy.

```
if (!$error && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['galleryFile']['tmp_name'])) {
        $format = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['galleryFile']['name'],"."),1));            
        $str = strtolower(trim($_FILES['galleryFile']['name']));
        $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]/', '-', $str);
        $str = preg_replace('/-+/', "-", $str);    
        $filename=$str.'.'.$format;                
        $uploadGallery=$origFileDir.$filename;
        foreach ($allowedImgFormats as $key => $value) {
            $value==$format ? $imgFormatOK='1' : NULL;
        }
        $imgFormatOK=='0' ? $error='You are attempting to upload an image with an invalid format!<br />Please only upload images with ".gif", ".jpg" or ".jpeg" extensions.' : NULL;
        if (!$error && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['galleryFile']['tmp_name'], $uploadGallery)){ 
            $galleryW='944'; $galleryH='733';                        
            $galleryInfo = getimagesize($uploadGallery);
            $memoryNeeded = Round(($galleryInfo[0] * $galleryInfo[1] * $galleryInfo['bits'] * $galleryInfo['channels'] / 8 + Pow(2, 16)) * 1.65);
            if ($memoryNeeded>=10000000) {
                unlink($uploadGallery); $error='The chosen image is too large to process.<br />Please upload a smaller image (lower dimensions and/or resolution).';
            } else {
                list($wOrig, $hOrig) = getimagesize($uploadGallery);
                $ratio_orig = $wOrig/$hOrig;
                if ($wOrig > $galleryW) { $galleryW = $galleryH*$ratio_orig; $galleryH = $galleryW/$ratio_orig; } else { $galleryW=$wOrig; $galleryH=$hOrig; }    
                if ($galleryH > $galleryH) { $galleryH = $galleryW*$ratio_orig; $galleryW = $galleryH/$ratio_orig; }
                $galleryP = imagecreatetruecolor($galleryW, $galleryH); 

                switch($format) {
                   case 'gif' : $thisGallery = imagecreatefromgif($uploadGallery); break;
                   case 'jpg' : $thisGallery = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadGallery); break;
                }
                imagecopyresampled($galleryP, $thisGallery, 0, 0, 0, 0, $galleryW, $galleryH, $wOrig, $hOrig);

                switch($format) {
                   case 'gif' : $createGallery=imagegif($galleryP, $galleryFileDir.$filename, 88); break;
                   case 'jpg' : $createGallery=imagejpeg($galleryP, $galleryFileDir.$filename, 88); break;
                }
                imagedestroy($galleryP); imagedestroy($thisGallery); unlink($uploadGallery);

                if (!$createGallery) {
                     $error='The chosen image failed to transfer correctly.<br />Please try again, or attempt to upload an alternative image.';
                     file_exists($galleryFileDir.'/'.$filename) ? unlink($galleryFileDir.'/'.$filename) : NULL;
                } else {            
                    $_POST['imagename']=$filename; 
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO isgallery(imagename, assoc_object) VALUES('".$_POST['imagename']."', '".$_POST['id']."')");                         
                }
            }        
        } else {
            !$error ? $error='The chosen image failed to upload correctly.<br />Please try again, or attempt to upload an alternative image.' : NULL;
            file_exists($uploadGallery) ? unlink($uploadGallery) : NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please *always, always* quote the error message you get. This is most likely a memory issue, in which case this is a good duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722352/php-memory-error-when-resizing-a-png-image

Comment: Uhm, any error message would be nice? It's most likely that you run out of memory when handling the image with GD..

Comment: [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) * cough * (`mysql_query("INSERT INTO isgallery(imagename, assoc_object) VALUES('".$_POST['imagename']."', '".$_POST['id']."')");`)

Comment: Apologies, but there was no error message, just a blank white screen.

Comment: What's the 'mysql_real_escape_string() * cough * ' about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 1000x1000 image requires at *LEAST* 3,000,000 bytes of memory if you're dealing with true color. and 4,000,000 if you're doing alpha transparency. Your `$memoryNeeded` variable is useless if it's set to something larger than PHP's [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit). It'll happily try to create an image and fail due to exceeded the limit.

You can check what the limit is with `ini_get('memory_limit')`, though you most likely won't be able to directly use this value for calculations without some massaging, as it'll likely return something like '32M' (32 megabyte limit), instead of `33554432`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Checked the memory limit and it came back as 128M!?

Comment: Ok, should be enough memory to handle the image. Check that your calculations are correct. Log/echo-out the $galleryW and $galleryH to make sure you're not creating an incredibly huge new image. Then start putting in debug statements at various stages in the function to see exactly where it dies. Could be some other problem, like a corrupt image.